# Unable to install Node.js in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I tried to install node in ubuntu 19.04 but I having lot's of 404 errors

**Curl :**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
```

**Log:**

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 12.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease             
Ign:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                      
Err:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco Release                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Get:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [10.4 kB]      
Ign:6 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable InRelease
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease               
Get:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages [20.8 kB]
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:10 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages [20.8 kB]
Hit:11 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release
Hit:13 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                     
Ign:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease             
Ign:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease           
Err:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
Err:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
Err:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu Disco is EOL you should edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Answer (score 2):

Install like this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Comment: Having issue with log : Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nodejs